# Update date in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i have a mysql database with client appointments table, i want to update appointments once a year by 364 days. That gives me the same Tuesday at 5:30pm one year later. I do not need to update to the same DATE, but the same DAY which is 364 days ... except leap year.

Please help

Comment: give me table structure

Comment: AppID,CusID,AppDate,AppTime,AppDay

Comment: So what exactly did you try and was not working?

Comment: i have no idea to do this :( i need sql statement for this

Comment: update to what?. And update the current record afer one year ah?

Comment: mass update sir, all dates to after one year

Comment: May be you get some idea from below sql structure
 ' select * from table_name where ((select DATEDIFF(day, AppDate,getDate()) AS DiffDate) > 364 and (select datename(dw,getdate()) ) = AppDay)'

Comment: thank you all i found the way. "UPDATE appoinment SET adate = DATE_ADD(adate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) and "UPDATE appoinment SET adate = DATE_ADD(adate, INTERVAL -1 day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use MySQL `DATE_ADD` function [full documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
Select DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

you can do the same in `UPDATE` statement where you would set your date columns

`SET MyDate = DATE_ADD(MyDate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`